# Open an Access database in LibreOffice Base

Tags: microsoft-access, ubuntu-18.04, libreoffice-base

I try to open a access database in LibreOffice Base

First, I installed LibreOffice

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Then I downloaded UCanAccess (http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) and unzipped it into the folder

```
~/Téléchargements/UCanAccess-3.0.7-bin
```

I launched LibreOffice, and chose Tools > Options.
On the Advanced tab I clicked the "Class Path..." button

[image: Options LibreOffice]

and then added the following JAR file using the "Add Archive..." button:

[image]

I launched LibreOffice Base, and in Step 1 of the wizard I chose "Connect to an existing database (JDBC)"

[image]

The Access file I wanted to manipulate was named "TEST.accdb" in my Téléchargements folder (Download in french)

[image]

In Step 3, I left the "User name" field empty and just clicked "Next >>".

In Step 4, I saved the LibreOffice Base database as "Nouvelle base de données.odb" in my Documents folder.

When the wizard completed it opened my LibreOffice database, i have this message error :

[image]

I tought i should need to add a parameter in Java Start Parameter

[image]

But it's not work. Theye are someone have a solution ? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT 01]

I use now UCanAccess 5.0.1 and correct the link

```
-DUCANACCESS_HOME=///home/za/Téléchargements/UCanAccess-5.0.1.bin
```

But now i have a new error

[image]

Comment: C:\ sounds like a Windows-path, but you're using Ubuntu. Make sure you actually entered the correct path.

Comment: Note also that UCanAccess 3.0.7 is a very old version. The most current version is 5.0.1

Comment: Besides the windows-like syntax (see Erik's comment), there might also be a typo in your Java start parameter. You wrote "Téléchargementz" ending with "z", but your path is named "Téléchargements" with "s".

Comment: FYI, I just tested the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236) with Xubuntu 20.04 and UCanAccess 5.0.1 and they still work fine.

Comment: @GordThompson  i add a edit

Comment: "The Access file I wanted to manipulate was named "TEST.accdb" in my Documents folder" - but your connection URL does not point to your "Documents" folder, it points to your home folder.

Comment: @GordThompson sorry, i write it without thinking traduction

Answer (score 0):

There is still something wrong in the path you wrote. There are three slashes where there should be only two:

```
-DUCANACCESS_HOME=//home/za/Téléchargements/UCanAccess-5.0.1.bin
```